# How to execute Kotlin Coroutine API services parallelly?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, mvvm, retrofit

I'm implementing a Login system in android Kotlin, Coroutine, Room and Retrofit using MVVM. Once the user is pressed Login Button, it executes fetchInitialApicalls() is executed.

```
fun fetchInitialApicalls(){
    fetchApi1()
    fetchApi2()
    fetchApi3()
...............

   fetchApi10()

}

fun fetchApi1(){
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           try{
               val response = demoRepository.fetchCall(request)
        
           }catch (e:Exception){

           }
        }
}
```

like that. fetchApi1() fetchApi2() etc. functions have to be called independently(This is working and it is a feature). My problem is when I execute fetchInitialApicalls() it only executes few functions inside it and gives me timeout. I increase retrofit timeout and it doesn't work.

Please tell me how to run this parallelly?

how to execute api calls parallelly?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html

Comment: Could you please explain me how to use it in this example?

Comment: Not exactly your code, but here's a standalone example: https://pl.kotl.in/BBqhFvrFz. Note that functions called within `async { ... }` don't have to be `suspend` functions themselves (they are in the example simply to allow calling `delay`).